# Find the number of items row wise with an exception

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, apply

I have a set of the following form:-

```
a <- data.frame(X1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "0"),
                X2=c("B", "A", "D", "E", "A"),
                X3=c("0", "0", "B", "A", "0"),
                X4=c("A", "0", "A", "0", "0")
                )

#                          a
#                    X1  X2  X3  X4
#                    A   B   0   A
#                    B   A   0   0
#                    C   D   B   A
#                    D   E   A   0
#                    0   A   0   0
```

What I want to know if in each row how many items are there except `"0"` and save them in a new column. The expected output should be :-

```
#            b
#            3
#            2
#            4
#            3
#            1
```

Duplicates should be counted as different, ie, if a row consists of 2 `"A"`, 1 `"B"` and a `"0"`, it should return 3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could compare the dataframe with 0 and use `rowSums` to calculate number of entries except 0 in each row.

```
rowSums(a != 0)
#[1] 3 2 4 3 1
```

Although, it is not needed here (since applying `rowSums` is straight-forward) we can also use `apply` row-wise :

```
apply(a!= 0 , 1, sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have **single character** in each cell of data frame `a`, then here is a base R option. Otherwise (if you have have any multiple characters in some cells), please turn to the approach by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60851326/12158757)

```
a$b <- nchar(gsub("0","",do.call(paste0,a)))
```

such that

```
> a
  X1 X2 X3 X4 b
1  A  B  0  A 3
2  B  A  0  0 2
3  C  D  B  A 4
4  D  E  A  0 3
5  0  A  0  0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lengths` with `split`

```
lengths(split(a[a!=0], row(a)[a  != 0]))
```